# A 'de + plural noun' phrase with 'un' understood

Tags: de

This sentence is from a novel published in 1960: 'C'était le premier jour chaud, un temps à aller enfin à la plage, de ceux qui incitent les élèves des grandes classes de l'école secondaire à ouvrir les capotes raides et craquelées de leurs cabriolets pour gagner les dunes en caravanes.' Am I right in understanding an 'un' before the 'de ceux qui'? And if so, is it common to see a 'de + plural noun' phrase on its own used like this?

Comment: Is the construction really 'de + plural noun'? Is it not rather 'noun +de + ceux + qui/que/dont/…'?

Comment: Your are quite right in thinking *un* would be omitted. This sort of commission is quite common to my mind. *Ceux* stands for  *ces jours*. But I don't understand what you mean by "de + plural noun' phrase".

Comment: Yes, I forgot 'ceux' is a pronoun not a noun. I was wondering if 'de ceux' or anything simliar that implies an 'un' might be a common formula in French.

Comment: (In the previous comment I meant **construction** and not "commission".) Doesn't English have a similar construction? "one of those that...." (*un de ceux qui... , de celles* qui... ) except that in English "of those" could be omitted, and not "one" ?

Answer (score 1):

**I**

Starting with the second question, we can state the conclusion that the construction "(noun/pronoun/adjective/être) + de + ceux (+ qui/que/dont/)", where  the preposition « de » is reckoned with as having  a partitive value **(**[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) : (b) Subst. + de. De a une valeur partitive, proche de celle de l'article partitif. Cf. *de*² et *des* II (en parlant d'une partie, d'un ensemble, d'un élément d'un tout) // c) Être de + subst.Faire partie de (le pron. pers. correspondant est en). Nous sommes du jury. // [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) P. méton. Être de ceux, celles; du nombre de ceux, celles qui. Être du même bord.**)**, is very common. Here is below the cases of occurrence of it that can be gathered from the first 1000 pages of *Le bon usage* (both examples and text provided as explantions by the authors of the book). Let's note that it is difficult, often enough, to determine whether "de" is used according to the above definition or not.

- […] j'estime être au contraire **un de ceux qui**, par la constance et la précision avec lesquelles
  ils la [= la ponctuation] manient, mériteraient d'être félicités.
- Dans plus d'un cas, le sème commun n'**est pas de ceux que** les dictionnaires explicitent dans leurs définitions.
- Car TELLE est l'évidence [...] : une grande **partie de ceux qui** ont été vaincus aux élections du Front populaire se sont reconnus dans l'itinéraire et les convictions de Rebatet
- Lorsque l'attribut d'un nom ou d'un pronom pluriels est formé de plusieurs noms coordonnés, **chacun de ceux-ci** est au singulier,  […]
- Cela se fait dans la langue courante lorsque les deux adjectifs sont **l'un et l'autre de ceux qui** s'antéposent ordinairement […]
- Si l'un des adjectifs, surtout le second, **est de ceux que** l'on n'antéposé pas d'ordinaire et, a fortiori, si les deux adjectifs sont […]
- Un des grands seigneurs de la psychologie classique, **un de ceux qui** lui ont fait rendre le MAXIMUM de ce DONT elle est SUSCEPTIBLE.
- Un petit **nombre de ceux qui** lui ressemblent ONT su s'arracher aux douceurs d'un spiritualisme nuancé.
- **Un de ceux qui** LIAIENT Jésus-Christ au poteau, / Et qui, sur son dos nu, JETAIENT un vil manteau
- Je suis assurément **un de ceux qui** SAIS le mieux reconnaître ces qualités-là
- **Un de ceux que** la discussion ne fait qu'obstiner dans SON sens […]
- Mon âme, j'en suis CERTAIN, a servi de miroir à **la plupart de ceux qui** y ont jeté les yeux
- Je ne **suis pas de ceux qui** se peuvent damner pour l'amour des jeunes fdles, MA mie !
- **La plupart de ceux qui** suivirent la semaine de prières auraient fait LEUR [...]
- **BEAUCOUP DE CEUX qui** sont montés sur les banquettes redescendent […]
- **BEAUCOUP DE CEUX-CI** connaissent la vérité.
- C'est [...] l'**un de ceux qui** [...] m'aura [sic] LE PLUS donné DE plaisir
- **Aucun de ceux qui** se soumettront ne sera puni.
- Un **mary (de CEUX-LÀ que**l'on perd sans pleure
- Afin que **NULS de ceux qui** ont de la justesse, de la vivacité [...] ne se reprochent pas même ce petit défaut
- Une grande composition bouillonne de rayons, d'enfants et d'anges, L'**UN de ceux-ci** tenant entre ses jambes un violoncelle
- Dans cet ex. comme dans la **plupart de ceux que** nous avons cités plus haut […]

*Not the same sense for "de"*

- C'est assurément un livre à tirer du **tas de ceux qui** comptent peu ou PROU […]
- Toutes les **catégories de ceux qui** NE manquent d'être où tout le monde va

> ([Wiktionnaire, de 16](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Fran%C3%A7ais) Rapport d’une chose à ce dont elle est formée, toujours avec complément indéterminé.

It is a construction with a first element of several sorts.

- noun [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) : (b) Subst. + de. De a une valeur partitive, proche de celle de l'article partitif. Cf. *de*² et *des* II (en parlant d'une partie, d'un ensemble, d'un élément d'un tout)
- ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre)) P. méton. Être de ceux, celles; du nombre de ceux, celles qui. Être du même bord.  (*user LPH: it can be seen that this is reduced to the preceding case since "être de ceux" is nothing else than an elliptic form of "être du nombre de ceux".*)
- pronoun (*this can be assimilated to the first category (of the nouns).*)
- adjective  in the comparative (*not found above but if not found too often, perfectly correct: le plus facile de ceux qui, le plus haut de ceux qui, etc.*)

**II**

- C'était le premier jour chaud, un temps à aller enfin à la plage, de ceux qui incitent les élèves des grandes classes de l'école secondaire à ouvrir les capotes raides et craquelées de leurs cabriolets pour gagner les dunes en caravanes.

What is to be seen in this construction is rather the ellipsis of a repetition, which, due to the re-characterization, is rather vague, although it can be taken as "temps". The final part in the sentence,  "de ceux … caravanes", is an apposition, hence the construction that implements it, must be nominal.

> ([Wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)) Apposition is a grammatical construction in which two elements, normally noun phrases, are placed side by side and so one element identifies the other in a different way. The two elements are said to be in apposition, and one of the elements is called the appositive, but its identification requires consideration of how the elements are used in a sentence.

Of course, placing "un" (pronoun with antecedent "temps") in front of this locution results in a correct  nominal group and in a meaningful sentence. As well, "un temps", where now "un" is just the article, will do.

- C'était le premier jour chaud, un temps à aller enfin à la plage, **un/un temps** de ceux qui incitent les élèves des grandes classes de l'école secondaire à ouvrir les capotes raides et craquelées de leurs cabriolets pour gagner les dunes en caravanes.

However, the following variants are flawless.

- C'était le premier jour chaud, un temps à aller enfin à la plage, **un jour** de ceux qui incitent les élèves des grandes classes de l'école secondaire à ouvrir les capotes raides et craquelées de leurs cabriolets pour gagner les dunes en caravanes.
- C'était le premier jour chaud, un temps à aller enfin à la plage, **un jour, un temps** de ceux qui incitent les élèves des grandes classes de l'école secondaire à ouvrir les capotes raides et craquelées de leurs cabriolets pour gagner les dunes en caravanes.

There is no rule telling the reader which ellipsis is that which applies, no rule saying that it has to be the ellipsis of a repetition of the noun that precedes. It might be argued that this is not as great an inconvenient as some could think it to be, that, approximately, we get the idea, and that we can leave it at that and not bother, assuming that the noun that precedes is more or less the relevant one. Personally, I think that the lack of definiteness makes for unease in the reading process, and that such sentences are defective on account of style.